# python3 how subtract (next to ) values in 2d Array?

Tags: python-3.x

Lets say this is one row of 2d array **"data"** , raw data begin from col.4 (1,9,15,39...)

`Anhui,China,31.8257,117.2264,1,9,15,39,60...`

I have this below script to subtract values of two (next to) members of array `(data[i][j]-data[i][j-1]` e.g. 9-1, 15-9, 39-15
however when I did debuging, I realised that it works some strange way,
specialy syntax data[i][j-1] not works the way I want,
script works only in 1st cycle then I get strange results,
Specialy I realized that after 1st cycle  it changed my source **"data"** array from 
1,9,15, to 1,8,15,
even I have no modification code for **data**, I want  making modifications in **data2**ii
Am I missing something ? Seems that in python Increment/Decrement Index in Array works different

```
for i in range (1,len(data)):
    for j in range (5,len(data[0])):
        diffr=(int(data[i][j])) - (int(data[i][j-1]))
        data2[i][j]=diffr
```

```
origin source 1,9,15,39,60
strange results 1,8,7,32,28,42
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both data and data2 are referencing to the same object. Might be you have done shallow copy of your data to data2.

Comment: how is possible?
Before this code, I made this operation> `data2=data`

Comment: Here is full code>  `import csv
datafile = open('sample11.csv', 'r')
datareader = csv.reader(datafile, delimiter=',')

data = []
for row in datareader:
    data.append(row)    


data2=data


for i in range (1,len(data)):
    for j in range (5,len(data[0])):
        diffr=(int(data[i][j])) - (int(data[i][(j-1)]))
        data2[i][j]=diffr



with open('export.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerows(data2)

`

Comment: so any idea how to separate to two objects?

Comment: You can use data2 = data[:] instead of data2 = data. Or you can use copy module to copy an object. i.e. import copy ; data2 = copy.deepcopy(data).

Comment: Excuse me what is difference btw data2 = data vs data2 = data[:] ?
I was thinking that when do varaible2 = variable1, it creates new variable with contents of variable2, as working in other languages,

Comment: OK, I found  in tutorial that if  m = n
Python does not create another object. It simply creates a new symbolic name or reference, m, which points to the same object that n points to.

Comment: But I havent found some tutorial explanation about m = n[:],
or how to create new variables, so if I have lets say  `n=5` and I want another variable I must do `m=n[:]`  right ?

Comment: Anyway, I tried your advice `data2=data[:]` but nothing changes, same weird results

Comment: No, new_var = var[ : ] is for iterable objects. For other objects use new_var = copy.deepcopy(var) .

Comment: I tried also this test variables, and seems here is different content, not working as symbolic link  `a=200
b=a
a=300
print (a)
print (b)
`>>
300
200

Comment: OK, tried also this version `data2 = copy.deepcopy(data)`
But got this err> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read23.py", line 12, in <module>
    data2 = copy.deepcopy(data)
NameError: name 'copy' is not defined

Comment: Have you imported copy module?

Comment: Here is the explanation :- a = 200 (a -> 200) b = a (b -> 200 because at this time a -> 200) a = 300 (a -> 300, b -> 200 because you didn't make any changes in 200)

Comment: ok, I Included `import copy`...  `data2 = copy.deepcopy(data)`but now I have same numbers >`source  1,9,15,39,60,70,106,152,200,237,
export  1,9,15,39,60,70,106,152,200,237,`
I have to debug, whats wrong

Comment: Ok, after debugging, script suddenly works smoothly. :) and results are correct, thx bro